# Symfony 2.1, composer and git repositories

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

With Symfony 2.0.x I store all my client side dependencies (jQuery, etc) in the deps file so I can easily update them all at once with vendor/install, with the switch to composer in 2.1 this is not possible. My options appear to be:

- Fork all repos and add in the composer.json file (pain in the butt and waste of time)
- Manually download them all and stick them inside my repo somewhere (also a pain in the butt)
- Write my own Grunt script or something similar

Does anyone have a solution for handling this, or am I going about it all wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Composer does have support for downloading libraries that are not Composer-aware. It's a little more work, but you can define each of your dependencies like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jquery/jquery",
                "version": "1.8.1",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "jquery/jquery": "1.8.1"
    }
}
```

Read more about it here: http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2.

This will download jQuery to `vendors/jquery/jquery` by default. I don't think there's a way to specify a directory outside of `vendors` at the moment, so that may considerably limit the usefulness of this suggestion.

FWIW, I would consider submitting a pull request/issue to the Composer Github project. This actually would make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it possible to pull from git? i.e. what is the equivalent of this:

[jQuery]
 git=git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git
 version=1.8.0